# Does irreducibility of a representation imply irreduciblity of all restricted representations?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group with a subgroup $H$. Then any representation of $G$ can be restricted to $H$. If the $G$ representation is irreducible then should the $H$ representation also be irreducible?

If not what would be a good counterexample?

I dont think its true.

I am thinking of a counterexample on these lines:
Let $(R, +)$ act on $R^
2$
by $a((x, y)) = (x + ay, y)$

We have a proper subrepresentation $R_1 = R(1, 0)$, where $R$ acts trivially.
This proves that our original representation is not irreducible.

Comment: Please include some context in which you came across this question or show your effort. You are more likely to get a solution that way.

Comment: What do you know about irreducible (complex) representations of abelian groups? Every group $G$ not of prime order has proper abelian subgroups $H$, which? Leaving a few dots for you to find and connect - at least for the time being.

Comment: irreducible (complex) representations of abelian groups are 1-dimensional. i dont see how this helps.

Comment: @Godin Take a group with a 2d irreducible representation but a proper abelian subgroup. Restrict the 2d irreducible representation to the abelian subgroup.

Comment: You could also try to consider the most extreme case when $H$ is the trivial group.

Answer (score 4):

The comments above explain that your question has a negative response and explains how to derive a counterexample. The easiest one to look at is the 2-dimensional irreducible representation $V$ of $S_3$ (over $\mathbb{C}$, say). This representation has basis $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$ and the simple transpositions $s_1=(12)$ and $s_2=(23)$ act by
\begin{align*}
s_1\alpha_1&=-\alpha_1 &s_1\alpha_2&=\alpha_1+\alpha_2\\
s_2\alpha_1&=\alpha_1+\alpha_2 &s_2\alpha_2&=-\alpha_2
\end{align*}
Since $S_3=\{1,s_1,s_2,s_1s_2,s_2s_1,s_1s_2s_1\}$ you can now work out the action of any element on this representation. It is not hard to verify that $V$ is irreducible (show there is no 1-dimensional subspace that is invariant under the action of both $s_1$ and $s_2$).

Now, note that $\alpha_1$ spans a 1-dimensional invariant subspace for the action of $s_1$. In particular, the restriction of $V$ to $H=\langle s_1\rangle$ is not irreducible.